# Python double quotes in os.system

Tags: python

I have a command in python:

```
os.system('echo {{"value": {0:0.0f}}} | /usr/bin/cmd -parameters'.format(value))
```

the thing is that I receive value instead of "value". I would like to have "value" in shell. I've tried with triple double quotes, with slashes and json.dumps. Nothing helped, still value instead of "value".

Could you help me?

Comment: use `subprocess` so the quoting is handled for you

Comment: Try using subprocess.call https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module this gives much better results.

Comment: @molbdnilo That's not related to the issue, that's only due to him not giving example of what value is. The string format is a dead give away of your issue. The missing quotes in output issue is not related to that.

Comment: @ThePjot Oh, yes. Of course.

Answer (score 2):

`os.system` is deprecated. Use `subprocess` instead, which will handle the quoting nicely for you.

Since you have a pipe, you would normally have to create 2 `subprocess` objects, but here you just want to feed standard input so:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/cmd","-parameters"],stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate('{{"value": {:0.0f}}}\n'.format(value).encode())  # we need to provide bytes
rc = p.wait()
```

The quoting issue is gone, since you're not using a system command to provide the argument, but pure python.

to test this I have changed the command to `more` so I can run it on windows (which also proves that this is portable):

```
import subprocess
value=12.0
p = subprocess.Popen(["more.com"],stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate('{{"value": {:0.0f}}}\n'.format(value).encode())
rc = p.wait()
```

that prints: `{"value": 12}`

Comment: This does not work, `value` is still unquoted in the output. You need to escape the double quotes around `value`

Comment: Which python version are you using. For me it outputs `{value: 12}` on mac with python 3.7.0

Comment: python 3.4. But you need `.encode()` for it to work (the first time I had forgotten it). Have you tried the "more" example without any changes?

Comment: Yeah, I already added the encode, but nevermind, the problem was on my site. Have your upvote.

Comment: I'm relieved. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to echo quotes, you need to escape them.

For example:

```
echo "value"
```

> value

```
echo "\"value\""
```

> "value"

So your python code should look like

```
os.system('echo {{\\"value\\": {0:0.0f}}} | /usr/bin/cmd -parameters'.format(value))
```

Note, that you should use double slashes `\\` because python would escape a single slash.

Comment: Correct, but not for os.system. Does not work on linux for example. `>>> os.system('echo {{"\"value\"": {0:0.0f}}}'.format(3))`
`{value: 3}`

Comment: You are right, I updated my answer.
You should use double slashes